# Torch or Light effect using Javascript or Jquery or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-effects

I need to torch or light source effect on an image/div on my webpage without the use of Flash.

This is something similar to the light path effect on the main banner on this site:

http://online.fullsail.edu/degrees/media-communications-bachelors?mnc=2602

Please advise.

Comment: right click and view the source code

Comment: Yes, I know how to right click and view source.. Please read my question again.. The site I mentioned has the feature using flash and my query was if it is possible to get that feature using jQuery or JavaScript or CSS??

Comment: I found the answer through css-tricks.com (http://jsfiddle.net/VvyUx/2/) .. http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/20013/how-to-get-a-torch-or-light-ray-effect-using-css-or-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this using CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/bFXzr/

**EDIT**: Posting code as requested in comment:

HTML

`<div class="box"></div>`​

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#000;
}

.box {
    margin:50px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50px;
    background:#ef5d22;
}

.box:hover {
    margin:50px;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:#ef5d22;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
}

​
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please post your code here and do not rely on jsfiddle or any other external site.

Comment: I have posted the code, but is there any rule to not refer to JSFiddle? I have seen hundreds of posts referring to jsFiddle?

Comment: jsFiddle is fine but having nothing valuable in your answer is not. See here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle and here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers Thank you very much for adding the code, it sets a good example for everyone else, and allows us to see what your answer is without leaving the site (many people do not require seeing it in action to understand the code).

Comment: Also see these links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115056/should-i-edit-posts-to-pull-in-the-code-from-jsfiddle

Comment: @Anshu Thanks, what you mentioned is a glow effect. My question was if it is possible to achieve Torch or Light source effect as shown in the site I mentioned (the site I mentioned has that using Flash)

Comment: Also to all the moderators.. Why is this question closed and not constructive. I have a technical query and I am asking some guidance from members here. Please respond.